# Syntax for list literals

Tags: agda

In Agda, what's the preferred way to write list literals, especially with multiple elements?

The best I could come up with is:

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.List

zeroElements oneElement multipleElements : List ℕ
zeroElements = []
oneElement = [ 0 ]
multipleElements = 0 ∷ 1 ∷ 2 ∷ []
```

(Note that `[ 0 ]` needs spaces inside the square brackets. Also note that `∷` is Unicode U+2237, not an ASCII double colon.)

I was hoping that the square bracket syntax would work with multiple elements, like `[ 0 , 1 , 2 ]`, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Am I reading [issue #235](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/issues/235) correctly that there is no more concise syntax for this right now?

Comment: In theory, this shouldn't have to be built into Agda itself. There's [PR 1499][1] currently open on the standard library for adding this syntax using only standard constructs. Unfortunately its currently blocked upstream by a small issue with the type-checker which isn't quite clever enough to handle it.  [1]: https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/pull/1499

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with before noticing you were linking to an issue
on the bug tracker and it's no improvement over the status quo at the time

```
module ListLiteral where

open import Agda.Builtin.List

infix 10 [_
infixr 15 _,_
infix 20 _]
pattern [_ x = x
pattern _,_ x xs = x ∷ xs
pattern _] x = x ∷ []

open import Agda.Builtin.Equality
open import Agda.Builtin.Nat

test : [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ] ≡ _
test = refl

open import Agda.Builtin.Bool

isSingleton : List Nat → Bool
isSingleton ([ _ ]) = true
isSingleton _ = false
```

Once we get typed pattern synonyms (NB: they are no active efforts to
implement them) it should at least solve the issue that the pattern `_,_`
clashes with the constructor for sigma types.

In my own projects I tend to just write `a ∷ b ∷ c ∷ ...`.